# How to delete a particular element from a matrix in SciLab

Tags: scilab

disp(A)

```
1.     4.     5.   
9.     13.    11.  
46.    29.    11.
```

-->clear A(3,3)
              !--error 276 
Missing operator, comma, or semicolon.

I want to delete 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clear` command is used to remove entire variables, see the [documentation](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/clear.html). If you could `clear` the 3,3 field it would result in a malformed matrix:

```
1.     4.     5.  
9.     13.    11.  
46.    29.
```

I don't know of a way this is possible.

What is it that you want? Do you want to set certain fields to be ignored. You could just set it to NaN (Not a Number) and check if it is nan later in your code with [isnan](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/isnan.html):

```
A = rand(3,3)

A(3,3)= %nan

disp(A)
non_nans_indices = find(~isnan(A))

disp(A(non_nans_indices))
```

Answer (score 0):

In a regular matrix you can not delete just one element, as stated in the above answer: you have to delete a full row or a full column. However in a sparse matrix you can. A sparse matrix stores only the non-zero elements of the matrix. So if your data doesn't contain valid elements with 0 value, you can "delete" any element by setting it to 0 and then converting the matrix into sparse form with the `sparse` command:

```
A=rand(3,3);
disp(A,"original matrix:");
A(3,3)=0;
disp(A,"element is nulled out:");
A=sparse(A);
disp(A,"sparse matrix:");
```

This way you doesn't store the 0 values of tha matrix which may save memory or storage space. If you want to convert back, you can use the `full` command: the "missing" elements are representeted with zeros again:

```
B=full(A);
disp(B,"full form:");
```

But I think, that for missing or invalid values it's better to use `%nan` as advised above too: it's easier to deal with, more consistent, and you can have zeros in the matrix as valid data.